# how many integers $n$ have the property that there exist positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^n+b^ n=c^n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

I want to know how to solve this question. I found this question in an online test but was not able to find the answer. Later after the test, when I reviewed the test, it showed the answer as $4$ but I want to know how the answer ends up in $4$.

I tried a lot but wasn’t able to find the answer.

Keep in mind that I’m a beginner and
$a,b$ and $c$ belong to $Z^+$ and $n$ belongs to $Z$

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699506/fermats-last-theorem-with-negative-exponent.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the question now. The way you stated it made the quantifiers unclear to me. The question is: how many integers $n$ have the property that there exist positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^n + b^n = c^n$?

Comment: $15^{-2}+20^{-2} = 12^{-2}$, $2^{-1} + 2^{-1} = 1^{-1}$, $1^1 + 1^1 = 2^1$, $3^2+4^2 = 5^2$ implies at least four possible values of $n$: $\pm 1, \pm 2$

Answer (score 1):

Fermart last theorem says that if $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\ge3$, then the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ means that at least one of $a,b,c$ are zero.

So, $n<3$. If $n\le-3$, $-n\ge3$, we have $$\begin{split}a^n+b^n&=c^n\\\bigg(\frac1a\bigg)^{-n}+\bigg(\frac1b\bigg)^{-n}&=\bigg(\frac1c\bigg)^{-n}\\(abc)^{-n}\Bigg(\bigg(\frac1a\bigg)^{-n}+\bigg(\frac1b\bigg)^{-n}\Bigg)&=(abc)^{-n}\bigg(\frac1c\bigg)^{-n}\\(bc)^{-n}+(ac)^{-n}&=(ca)^{-n}\end{split}$$

which has no solutions from Fermart Last Theorem.

So it remains to check the case when $n=-2,-1,0,1,2$. The casework is left for an exercise.

Comment: Minor nitpick: FLT is when $n \geq 3$.